# Validating uniqueness of struct field values with cue

Tags: validation, yaml, cuelang

I'm evaluating using a [cue](https://cuelang.org/) schema to replace bespoke validation code for an existing YAML format that looks something like this:

```yaml
items:
  - name: a
    description: something
  - name: b
    description: other thing
```

Following the [tutorials](https://cuelang.org/docs/tutorials/) has made it pretty easy to get the basics working: enforcing the required and optional fields on each item, and their types and value constraints.

However, a feature of the existing validation code that I'd like to replicate is the ability to enforce that no two entries in the `items` list share the same value for `name`. It's not obvious to me from the documentation whether or how this might be possible with cue. Is it?

(I know that I could and maybe should just use a map here instead of a list, and promote the name field into a key in the map, but I'd like to avoid changing the YAML format for the benefit of the validation code / tool if possible.)

Here's a specific example of the kind of thing that I'd want to fail validation (because the `name` `a` is reused):

```yaml
items:
  - name: a
    description: something
  - name: a
    description: other thing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm VERY new to CUE and there's probably a better solution to this.

The solution I could think of is having a guard-like private variable `_uniqueName: true` and leveraging the fact that CUE will fail validation if we try to assign a conflicting value to the same var. Therefore you could reassign `_uniqueName` to a result of `list.UniqueItems` after massaging the items list first.

See https://cuelang.org/play/?id=WZyVeYCEsEM#cue@export@yaml

Granted the error message is not the most descriptive one or doesn't show you which value is duplicated, but it generally does what you need/asked.

To improve a bit you could e.g. rename the variable to `_namesInItemsMustBeUnique`.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed does the trick, though you're right that the error message "failed to encode: _uniqueName: conflicting values true and false" leaves something to be desired.

Comment: The `error` builtin would enable meaningful messages for use cases like this. (https://github.com/cue-lang/cue/issues/943) The Associative List proposal may also help, depending on your desired UX. (https://cuetorials.com/cueology/futurology/associative-lists/) Both are likely to be accepted and something to keep an eye on.